# How to get const from interface on PHP

Tags: php, arrays, class, interface

Just been searching and don't seem to find anything related to this.

I have an interface like this:

```
interface exampleInterface
{
    const _TYPE = array(
        "name1" => "0",
        "name2" => "1",
        "name3" => "2"
    );

    public function x();
}
```

And also a class which implements this interface.
How can I get the value of something like `_TYPE["name1"]`
Can it be done?

Edit: "Arrays are not allowed in class constants"

Comment: That code won't compile with any version of PHP below 5.6 (currently in beta) http://3v4l.org/8Yl8V

Comment: Arrays are not allowed in class constants

Comment: Thank you for the fast response.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest you another approach:

```
abstract class exampleBaseClass
{
    const _TYPE_NAME1 = "0";
    const _TYPE_NAME2 = "1";
    const _TYPE_NAME3 = "2";

    abstract public function x();

    protected function getType($name) {
        return constant('exampleBaseClass::_TYPE_' . strtoupper($name));
    }
}
```

Access const from derived class's method:

```
exampleBaseClass::_TYPE_NAME1
```

or

```
$this->getType('name1');
```

Comment: If you use a class instead, then you can use `protected static $_TYPE = array(...)`. Also, they may be looking to leverage interfaces for another reason.